# Attaching a small rhombus with a circular bullet at its bottom

Tags: tikz-cd, shapes, bullets

I wanna attach (means by adding a second arrow) a small rhombus with a circular bullet at its bottom to the following drawing:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
    \begin{document}
 \[
      \begin{tikzcd}[sep = 2em,
        /tikz/rhombus/.style={shape=diamond,draw,minimum size=2em},
        execute at end picture={
          \draw [densely dashed] (foo.north west) -- (foo.north east);
          \draw [densely dashed] (foo.south west) -- (foo.south east);
        }
        ]
     |[rhombus,draw,minimum size=3em, alias=foo]|{}\arrow[r,shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em] & 
     |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\myln\tikzlastnode}
     (\myln.north) node[anchor=south,rhombus] {}
     (\myln.south) node[anchor=north,rhombus] {}}]|{}\\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please make complete examples from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, containing the necessary packages etc. Where is the new rhombus supposed to be placed?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok I will edit my post ... sorry about that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ihave just edited it.

Comment: My question still stands: where is this new rhombus supposed to be placed? And also, where should the second arrow be?

Comment: To the right of the current figure, I want to draw a right arrow and then the rhombus (supposed to have the same size as one of the small rhombi already drawn before)with the bullet at its bottom to the right of the drawn arrow ..... Is this an answer to your question?@TorbjørnT.

Comment: It be far more clear if you attach to question a sketch, what you like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure guessing ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\[
        \begin{tikzcd}[sep = 2em,
     every arrow/.append style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
      shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
       /tikz/dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}},
   /tikz/rhombus/.style = {diamond, draw, minimum size=#1, outer sep=0pt},
 /tikz/rhombus/.default = 2em,
 execute at end picture = {\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 1pt] 
                            (foo.north west) -- (foo.north east)
                            (foo.south west) -- (foo.south east);
                          }
                    ]
|[rhombus=3em, alias=foo]|{} \rar[shorten <>=1ex] 
    & |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
            (\LN.north) node[rhombus,above] {}
            (\LN.south) node[rhombus,below] {}
                                     }]|{}  \rar[shorten <>=1ex] 
        & |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
            (\LN.south) node[dot]
                                     }]|{}
        \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was describing.